# Is there a complete list of values for the various Java cards for EMV tag 9F7E - Application Life Cycle Data?

Tags: smartcard, emv, mastercard

I am working on some various EMV Java Chip cards, and I am trying to identify the values for EMV tag 9F7E - Application Life Cycle Data.  Thus, I searched the world wide web, talked to card manufactures, but as of yet I have not seen a complete list of them.

Do you know where I might find a list of Card Type to Application Life Cycle Data (First 8 Bytes)?

Thanks,

Your Humble Learner

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Application Life Cycle Data is to uniquely identify the
application code and the application issuer.

The first byte is version number, with value ‘02’ for M/Chip Lite 4, and ‘03’ for M/Chip Select 4. The next seven bytes are for Type Approval identification code.

The seven bytes reserved for the Type Approval ID contain an identifier given
by MasterCard when the application passes the Type Approval process.

You must ask to MasterCard to get complete list but I do not think they would give them to anyone.

Comment: Right, but I have some projects failing FIME do to the fact 9F7E doesn't match the card type. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I think Fime should only control first byte thats Application type.